# Django: sorl-thumbnail doesn't work at production mode(DEBUG=False) in local machine(Mac OS)

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, sorl-thumbnail

I used `sorl-thumbnail` for creating thumbnail image in my django project.

Before I deploy my django application in real AWS server, I ran it in my local machine(Mac OS)

When run in development mode(`DEBUG = True` in `settings.py`), it works perfectly. Thumbnail image loads well in any pages.

When I changed to production mode(`DEBUG = False` in `settings.py`), it doesn't work at all! All thumbnail images were not loaded, not even one!

It shows error in terminal like this:

```
[30/Nov/2016 13:13:14] "GET /media/cache/37/91/37915dc65a819027b65457f40c25580b.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 128
```

When I accessed this image through url directly(http://localhost:8000/media/cache/37/91/37915dc65a819027b65457f40c25580b.jpg), it shows `Not Found` error.

But thumbnail file(`37915dc65a819027b65457f40c25580b.jpg`) is located in `MY_COLLECTSTATIC_FOLDER/media/cache/37/91/`.

I have no idea why page can not load this cached thumbnail image file.

Comment: Django development server handles media and static only in debug mode. In production some other server must do it.

Comment: Oh, really? You mean, I cannot run my django-application as a production mode in my local machine?

Comment: You can, but [without static files serving](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev What if I add `--insecure` option when `runserver`?

Comment: I don't know, I've never done such strange things.